# Convert acceleration as a function of position to acceleration as a function of time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, time, acceleration

Suppose I have acceleration defined as a function of position, $a(x)$. How to convert it into a function of time $a(t)$? Please give an example for the case $a(x)= \frac{x}{s^2}$.

Comment: The homework tag doesn't just apply to actual homework problems here, it applies to any questions of an educational nature. That being said, I think this might be general enough that it doesn't actually need the homework tag - especially if you were to remove the request for an example.

Answer (score 8):

Conserning the general case, there is a way to use potential and kinetic energy (every acceleration corresponds to a force on a point mass, and every force in 1 dimension has a potential energy V such that $F=\frac{-dV}{dx}$), but there is a more mathematical solution:

You know $a(x)$ (and, thus, $F(x)$), $v_0(x_0)$ and $t_0(x_0)$ as boundary conditions (otherwise the answer is ambiguous). You need to find $a(t)$.

The general definition:

$$a(x)=\frac{d v(x)}{d t}=\frac{d v(x)}{d x}\frac{d x}{d t}=\frac{d v(x)}{d x}v(x)$$

Recombine the differentials:

$$a(x)dx=v(x)dv(x)$$

Integrate both parts:

$$\int_{x_0}^x a(x)dx=\int_{v_0}^v v(x)dv(x) = \frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2}$$
Solve for $v(x)$:

$$v(x)=\sqrt{v_0^2+2\int_{x_0}^x a(x)dx}$$

Now, let's find $t(x)$. We will first find it`s derivative:

$$\frac{d t(x)}{d x}=\frac{1}{v(x)}$$

Again, split the differentials and integrate:

$$\int_{t_0}^t dt=\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{v(x)}=\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{v_0^2+2\int_{x_0}^x a(x)dx}}$$
Evaluate the leftmost integral:

$$t=t_0+\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{v_0^2+2\int_{x_0}^x a(x)dx}}$$

Solving for x allows you substitute it and get $a(t)$.

This works perfectly when $x(t)$ is a 1-to-1 correspondence, but fails (to give the right answer), when the motion changes direction. In your case it seems that 1/s^2 is meant to be a positive real, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

rewrite as the function:
$ a_{(x)} = \frac {x}{s^2}   = \ddot {x} $

this differential equation can be rewritten as:

$ \ddot {x} - \frac{x}{s^2}   = 0 $

interestingly we need not go any further since obviously the 2nd derivitive must be equal to the function itself. THe obvious solution is some linear combination of hyperbolic functions

$a_{(t)}  =  A \sinh(st) + B \cosh(st)  $

etc.
if we are treating x as an independent variable, I think this is the only correct solution. this is not a SHO

Comment: this is the explicit solution... i guess david zaslanvasky didn't want to do your hw for you and gave you the answers to other similar problems

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to express position as a function of time, then for any time you can calculate the corresponding position and thus the acceleration.

$$a(t) = a(x(t))$$

So basically, you need to find the function $x(t)$. To do so, you need to solve the differential equation

$$a(x) = \ddot{x}$$

where $\ddot{x}$ denotes the second derivative of $x$ with respect to time.

In general, the solution to this equation is [quite complicated](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+d%5E2+x%2Fdt%5E2+%3D+C+x%5En). But there are certain special cases that are easily solvable. One that comes up very often in the solution of gravitationally bound systems (such as orbital motion) is
$$a(x) = -C x^{-2}$$
($C$ is a positive constant) which is discussed in [this other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/dont-heavier-objects-actually-fall-faster-because-they-exert-their-own-gravity/3547#3547) I posted a while back. Another common case - in fact, probably even more common - is the simple harmonic oscillator,
$$a(x) = -C x$$
which has the solution
$$x(t) = A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t)$$
where $\omega = \sqrt{C}$. You can also do the trivial case of constant acceleration,
$$a(x) = -C$$
which corresponds to such things as straight-line projectile motion.