# Converting a(x) to a(t)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I had this question and found an answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15964)
. He says that $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x)$$
Isn't it wrong?, shouldn't that be $v(t)$ meaning you have to solve the differential equation with $$x''(t)=a(x(t))$$.

Comment: If x is taken over a continuum of space as well as time, it's not necessarily wrong. A more precise definition in that case would be $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)$$

Comment: Or, better yet, $v(x(t))$.

Comment: It should be $$\ddot{x} = a(v)$$ since acceleration is a function of velocity _only_ regardless of time or position.

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon to get equations like this. For example the [viscous drag on an object is proportional to the velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law), so we get the equation:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = -kv $$

for some constant $k$. To solve this equation just rearrange it to give:

$$ \frac{dv}{v} = -k\,dt $$

then integrate both sides:

$$ \int\frac{dv}{v} = \int -k\,dt $$

to get:

$$ ln(v) = -kt + C $$

where $C$ is the constant of integration, or in a more familiar form:

$$ v = D e^{-kt} $$

This is a particularly simple example, but the general method is the same even where $f(x)$ is a complicated function. In your case you would solve the equation using:

$$ \int\frac{dx}{v(x)} = \int dt $$