# Finding speed as a function of time from acceleration as a nonlinear function of position

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, differential-equations

For general function $x'' = G(x)$ with $x(t=0) = x_0$ and $x'(t=0) = v_0$, what could the general form of $x'(t)$ be?

I was able to do a derivation similar to:

[Convert acceleration as a function of position to acceleration as a function of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15805/convert-acceleration-as-a-function-of-position-to-acceleration-as-a-function-of)

But it only gives velocity as a function of position. Is it possible to get a simpler expression of $v(t)$ without using the last integral in that post to find $x(t)$ and subtituting it to find $v(t)$?

Comment: It seems like at a minimum you could write $x=\iint G + v_0 t + x_0$

Answer (score 0):

$$v(x)=\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$dt=\frac{dx}{v(x)}$$
$$t=\int{\frac{dx}{v(x)}}$$

Comment: Hi Chet, thank you for the answer, but I was looking for an axpression where I dont have to use the last equation in the linked question to find x(t), your answer gives t as a function of x