# Radial fall in a Newtonian gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, orbital-motion, free-fall

Suppose an object of mass $m$ starts at rest at a radial distance $ r_0$ from a perfectly spherical mass $M$ (where $m << M$), $r_0 > R =$ radius of $M$.

Can we analytically determine when $m$ will hit the surface of the $M$?

In other words, can we analytically solve this initial value problem:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2} ~=~ - \frac{GM}{r^2} ,$$
$$ \dot{r}(0) ~=~ 0 ,$$
$$ r(0) ~=~ r_0? $$

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34366/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that is covered by [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3547/124) I posted some time ago to a related (but not quite the same) question. Adapting it to your notation,

$$t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2G(m + M)}}\biggl(\sqrt{r_0 R(r_0 - R)} + r_0^{3/2}\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{R}{r_0}}\biggr)$$

The same formula is given in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field) Qmechanic mentioned in a comment.