# Finding reduced mass equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I want to find reduced mass using newtonian mechanics but I fail. Can someone help me to find my mistake?

My work :
[image: FigA]

I'm not sure why the final equation has a negative in left side but right side is positive.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252511/392 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159390/392 about why reduced mass comes out of systems where two bodies interact.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$
you have  two equations

$$ \b{\ddot{r}}_1=\frac{1}{m_1}\b F_{12}$$
$$ \b{\ddot{r}}_2=\frac{1}{m_2}\left(-\b F_{12}\right)$$

obtain  equation (1) minus equation (2)
$$\b{\ddot{r}}_1-\b{\ddot{r}}_2=\b{\ddot{r}}=
\left(\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2}\right)\,\b F_{12}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\mu\,\b{\ddot{r}}=-\frac{G\,m_1\,m_2}{\b r^2}\,\b{\hat{r}}\\
\mu=\frac{m_1\,m_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your time.