Centre of mass and reduced mass in classical mechanic
Can we derive reduced mass from Cetre of mass equation if CM is not taken as origin?
And Under what conditions can reduced mass concept be used or not?

Reduced mass is used in two-body problems. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159271/123208 & links therein

The reduced mass comes exactly from the center of mass being at the origin of the coordinate system for a two-body system.

@MattHanson Reduced mass has nothing to do with the position of the center of mass. Things go the other way around. Since the equation of motion for the relative position does not depend on the position of the center of mass, in many cases, we can simplify the analysis by choosing the origin as coinciding with the center of mass position.

Perhaps you misunderstood my point. The entire concept of the reduced mass in rotational mechanics comes about specifically because you can derive what the moment of inertia for a two body system looks like when the center of mass is at the origin of the body fixed frame. This results in the reduced mass times the square of the distance between the bodies. Hence, the reduced mass arises in the consideration of inertia (though it is not all of the inertia)

@MattHanson Since what you are referring to is not the only way of introducing the reduced mass, the exact position of the center of mass cannot play a fundamental role.

In the two-body problem for two bodies whose position is represented by two position vectors ${\bf r}_1$ and ${\bf r}_2$, it is helpful to rewrite the equations of motion (it doesn't matter if classical or quantum), in terms of the two variables
$$
\begin{align}
{\bf r} &= {\bf r}_2 - {\bf r}_1\\
{\bf R} &= \frac{m_1 {\bf r}_1 + m_2 {\bf r}_2}{m_1+m_2}.
\end{align}
$$
The equation for ${\bf r}$ can be read as the equation of motion of a body of mass $\mu$, the reduced mass, defined through
$$
\frac{1}{\mu}= \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2}.
$$
For example, in the case of Newtonian mechanics, in the presence of a central force, we have
$$
\begin{align}
m_1\ddot{\bf r}_1 &= ~~\Phi(r){\bf r}\tag{1}\\
m_2\ddot{\bf r}_2 &= -\Phi(r){\bf r}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
By dividing equation ($1$) by $m_1$, and equation ($2$) by $m_2$ and subtracting , we get an equation of the form
$$
\mu \ddot {\bf r} = -\Phi(r){\bf r}.
$$
From these completely general formulas, it should be clear that the position of the center of mass does not matter. ${\bf R}$ may be the null vector or any other vector, even changing with time, without affecting the change of variables and the definition of the reduced mass.
