# Final positions and velocities of two bodies, given initial position and velocities, masses, and a force law $f(r)$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

How would I find the final positions and velocities of two bodies given the initial positions and velocities of both objects, the masses of both objects, and some force law $f(r)$, which is some function of distance $r$?  I understand one way to approximate the final positions and velocities is using a simulation that uses time step increments, but how would I calculate the final positions and velocities of two bodies without using time step increments?  How would I calculate the final positions and velocities by hand?

Comment: A typical upper-division or graduate text on mechanics spends at least a chapter on this subject. And not a short or easy chapter, either. I think the topic is simply too big for a Stack Exchange question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kepler problem in time: how do two gravitationally attracted particles move?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28519/kepler-problem-in-time-how-do-two-gravitationally-attracted-particles-move)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the alleged duplicate is on the inverse square law, not in the case of a generic force law $f(r)$.

Answer (score 1):

You solve Newton's, Lagrange's or Hamilton equations which leads to a system of ordinary differential equations with the given initial positions and velocities as initial conditions. For the two-body problem, the solution can often be found analytically by using conservation laws (energy, momentum, angular momentum, ...).

Comment: +1 This very vague answer is the best one I can think of for this very vague question.