# Time in movement for forces as functions of position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Let there be an object in rest of $1kg$ mass at $x=0$ and a force acted upon it which can be described by the equation

$F(x) = \frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}$

with $x$ belonging in $[0,1/2]$. I want to know in how much time it will move by $1/2 m$.

sο what I need is a way to connect  $x$ with $t$ (where $t$ is time).

neuton's second law of motion states that $F=ma$ where $m$ is the mass of the object and $a$ its acceleration

so $F=ma=1a=a$ but $a= \frac{du}{dt}= \frac{du}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{du}{dx} u$ so $\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2} = \frac{du}{dx} u <=> \frac{dx}{(1-2x)^2} = u du <=> \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-2x} = \frac{1}{2} u^2 <=> \frac{1}{1-2x} = u^2$

Comment: Please show us any of your own effort.

Comment: ok 2 things ... first of all i need a second opinion .... and secondly thats why i ask, to get the answer (+where ?? in the comments?? )

Comment: It's site policy for *HW&E* questions that the OP shows his own effort. You can easily edit your question to that effect. Who do you mean by*1/2m*?

Comment: hmmmm alright .. and what do you mean by "who do you mean by *1/2m*"??

Comment: @AntonisSk Please supply initial position and initial velocity as well.

Comment: You are doing well so far. Now that you have an equation for $u=\frac{dx}{dt}$ as a function $x$, the variables $x$ and $t$ are separable so you can integrate this equation easily.

Comment: I meant what does "1/2m" stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be
$$\int_0^x \frac{dx}{(1-2x)^2}=\int_0^u udu$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1-2x}\right]_0^x=\frac{u^2}{2}$$
$$u^2=\frac{1}{1-2x}-1$$
So
$$\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}=(u^2+1)^2$$

Then
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}=(u^2+1)^2$$
$$\int_0^u\frac{du}{(u^2+1)^2}=\int_0^t dt$$
By substitution with $u=\tan\theta$, we have
$$t=\frac{1}{2}\left[\arctan u + \frac{u}{1+u^2}\right]$$
Now, when $x\to 1/2$, $u\to+\infty$

Time taken is $\pi/4$.

Comment: alright but can you show me how did you get t = ... I mean I get what you are doing but i want to see it in detail

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body

Comment: cant you show on your solution how you end up with t=1/2 (arctan u + u/(u^2 +1)) ???  you just jumped to the end .... can you please add the part im asking?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34366/time-taken-for-object-in-space-to-fall-to-earth

Comment: still I didnt get the answer i wanted ... but its ok i will read the article a bit more