# One dimensional motion with changing acceleration. Falling to a large body from a great distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, kinematics, classical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Radial fall in a Newtonian gravitational field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19388/radial-fall-in-a-newtonian-gravitational-field)

My math and physics are rusty. I am trying to calculate the time an object takes to fall to a large body. Before you answer $1/2at^2$, the conditions where $1/2at^2$ apply is where $a$ is a constant. Constant acceleration is a fine approximation when the distance the object falls is $<<$ than the distance to the center of the large body. i.e. 100 meters on the surface of the Earth.

I'm looking at problems where distance fallen is 50% or more of the distance between objects.

Gravity varies with the inverse square of distance. Given two bodies, $m_s$ and $m_l$.

$$ F = m_sa = m_la $$
$$ F = Gm_sm_l/r^2 $$
$$ m_sa = Gm_sm_l/r^2 $$
$$ a = Gm_l/r^2 $$

Thus acceleration of $m_s$ varies with the inverse square of the distance to the center of $m_l$, and versa visa.

Given R is the radius of the $m_l$, defining the surface of $m_l$. Given $h$ is the distance $m_s$ is above $m_l$'s surface, subsitute $R+h$ for $r$.

$$ a = Gm_l/(R+h)^2 $$

This is as discussed at [stackexchange 35878](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35878/is-acceleration-due-to-gravity-constant).

Given the initial velocity of $m_s$ is zero, what is the time, $t$, it takes $m_s$ to fall distance $h$?

An alternative question is give a $t$, how far with $m_s$ fall?

This is where I'm rusty. I don't believe one can't simply substitute $Gm_l/(R+h)^2$ for $a$ in $1/2at^2$, but I don't know what else to do.

The stackexchange articles, [15587](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15587/distance-when-acceleration-not-constant) and [41741](http://physics.stacskexchange.com/questions/41741/linear-motion-with-variable-acceleration), discuss $a(x)$ where $a$ changes linearly with distance. Here $a$ changes with the inverse square of the distance.

I did a lot of web searching and did not find this topic discussed. The discussions are with $a$ being constant or changing in a linear manner.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19388/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic - Yes the links do answer my question. I missed these questions as they did not have the tags I thought they should--Now how do I 'finish' this question? What is the appropriate way to close this question?

Comment: The simplest is to flag a moderator, and ask him to close it as a duplicate.