# Any way to Find the Position Function of a body under gravitational force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

Here's the problem I am trying to find a solution to:

> Consider a heavy point particle of mass $m_2$ fixed at a point (preferably the origin) and another light point particle of mass $m_1$ at an initial separation of $r_i$ from the fixed particle. There are no other bodies that can interfere with their interaction. Given any time $>t$, what will be the separation $r$ of the two particles at that time?

I tried to solve this myself with the following procedure:

$$E = K_E + P_E$$ where $E$ is the constant total energy, $K_E$ and $P_E$ the kinetic and potential energies of the light particle respectively. Elaborately,
$$\frac{-Gm_2m_1}{r_i}=\frac{1}{2}m_1v^2-\frac{Gm_2m_1}{r}$$ Solving for $v$ gives me
$$v=\sqrt{2Gm_2(\frac{r-r_i}{rr_i})}$$ after that 
I get to a halt when this appears
$$t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2Gm_2}}\int{\sqrt{\frac{rr_i}{r_i-r}}dr}$$
which I cannot solve further, So I post this question in Mathematics Stack Exchange, and a satisfying answer to the integral they give is 
$$t=r_i\sqrt{r_i}\ln\left(\sqrt{r}+\sqrt{r-r_i}\right)+\sqrt{r(r+r_i)}-\frac{r_i\sqrt{r_i}\ln\left(\sqrt{r_i}\right)}{\sqrt{2Gm_2}}-(r-r_i)^2$$
which doesn't seem correct by the way. Differentiating this again must get me back to where i started  but I don't get there. Is there any other way to solve such a question or is this the best that can be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kepler problem in time: how do two gravitationally attracting particles move?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28519/)

Comment: Fixed the last equation so that it at least displays, but did not verify for correctness. At a glance, it appears to be dimensionally incorrect. @The Light Spark, you should probably correct this.

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field). Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19388/2451  and links therein.