# Solve the inverse function of the solution to a varying acceleration problem ODE

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, coulombs-law, free-fall

Suppose there are two positive charges $A$ and $B$, both with equal mass $m$ and the same charge quantity $q$. The initial distance between $AB$ is $R$; and the initial velocity of $B$ relatively to $A$ is $0$.

[image]

Suppose the reference coordinate system is using $A$ as the origin and $AB$ as $x$-axis; $r$ is the distance $B$ moves under the Coulomb's force

$$F(t)=\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0\left(R+r(t)\right)^2}$$

Then I obtained the 2nd order nonlinear ODE:

$$\frac{dr(t)}{dt}=v(t)$$
and
$$\frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=a(t)=2\frac{F(t)}{m}=\frac{q^2}{2\pi m\epsilon_0\left(R+r(t)\right)^2}$$

with initial/boundary conditions
$$r(t)=0,\quad r'(t)=0$$

Questions are:

1. How to find the exact solution $r(t)$ of the ODE ?
2. How to find the exact solution $t(r)$ which is the inverse function of $r(t)$?

Comment: The charge A is attached to the origion all the time?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of the analogous gravitational problem: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19388/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you, the link is very useful! For the ODE, I also want to find both $r(t)$ and its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, define the variable $u(t)=R+r(t)$, so your equation can be put as:

\begin{equation}
{d^2u\over dt^2}={k\over u^2}, \text{ where $k$ is a constant}
\end{equation}

Then, multiply by $du/dt$ both sides of this equation, leaving:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&{du\over dt}{d^2u\over dt^2}={k\over u^2}{du\over dt}\\
&\Rightarrow&{1\over 2}{d\over dt}\left({du\over dt}\right)^2=-{d\over dt}\left({k\over u}\right)\\
&\Rightarrow&{d\over dt}\left[\left({du\over dt}\right)^2+{2k\over u}\right]=0\\
\end{eqnarray}

Then you have:

\begin{equation}
\left({du\over dt}\right)^2+{2k\over u}=C,\text{ where $C$ is a constant}
\end{equation}

Finally:

\begin{equation}
{du\over dt}=\pm\sqrt{C-{2k\over u}},
\end{equation}
which you can solve easily (fifty points to gryffindor!!!)

Comment: This answer is acceptable plus @Qmechanic 's links. BTW: What does the `fifty points to gryffindor` mean?