# Motion described by $a=\frac{k}{x^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Say a particle in one dimension experiences acceleration inversely proportional to the square of displacement. What is its displacement as a function of time?

$$
a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{k}{x^2} \\
\text{a second-order nonlinear differential equation, apparently}
$$

For context, the particle could be gravitationally attracted to a fixed mass $m$, in which $k$ would be $Gm$, where $G$ is the gravitational constant.

I can’t seem to find a solution to this apparently simple problem.
Is $x(t)$ very complex? What about $v(t)$, or $a(t)$? Which of these can be expressed simply in terms of $t$?

---

**P.S.** It seems that the particle’s acceleration would be infinite when $x=0$, but only for an infinitesimal instant. Does that mean the velocity spikes to infinity, or does it reach a maximum?

Comment: Be careful about your signs.  In the physical problem, when x is positive, the acceleration will be negative and vice versa.  Your equation doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19388/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

First let $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$, thus we have,

$a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{k}{x^2}$

Now using the chain rule, $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = v\frac{dv}{dx}$

Therefore,

$v\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{k}{x^2}$

Re-arranging and integrating gives,

$\int v\ dv = \int \frac{k}{x^2} dx$

and therefore,

$\frac{v^2}{2} = -\frac{k}{x} + C$

Or,

$v^2 = \frac{-2k}{x} + C$

for some constant $C$ dependent on initial conditions.

I'll leave as a simple exercise for the reader to now set $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ and solve for $x(t)$

Comment: They will not be able to solve for $x(t)$; the best we can obtain is an approximation or a non-linear algebraic relation involving $x(t)$ and $t$.

Comment: @JamalS Well I have a solution but there are no margins to contain it.

Comment: @Mew Can you please share your progress? Consider me incapable…

Comment: @Mew That is incorrect. There *is* an analytical solution here, available if you're not too lazy to go looking for it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, oh ok, then my answer stands where I leave this as an exercise for the reader :)