The acceleration due to gravity - differential equation
The law of universal gravitation states:
$$\vec{F}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
where we have the familiar $m$ for the small mass and $M$ for the big mass, $r$ being the distance between the center of  masses of the two bodies. We can set this equation equal $mg$ where $g$ is  the gravitational acceleration - we then have:
$$\vec{g}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
Assume an object which is very far from the big mass, and also assume that that object has relatively small mass compared to the big mass (i.e. $\ll M$), so that it does not produce strong gravitational field that would move the big mass. We then have this differential equation:
$$\ddot{r}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
What then would be the solution to this equation? My attempt looked like this:
$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
We can use the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{d}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt} \Longrightarrow \frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2$$
which is then,
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$
Then integrating the expression gives us:
$$\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{GM}{r}+\mathrm{const}.$$
And I cannot solve this. I am not even sure if my method of solving this is correct, can someone help me or give me a link to a solution?

multiply the equation with $\frac{dr}{dt}$ and know what the derivative of $(\frac{dr}{dt})^2$ is

See for example the Kepler problem on Wikipedia.

The differential equation should be an equation for a vector. Missing that, there would be no orbit at all. This subject is treated in detail in every textbook on classical mechanics.

Your equation should have a factor of 1/2 on the left-hand side. If you correct this, it becomes equivalent to the statement that the energy of the particle (kinetic plus potential) is conserved.

As far as solving it goes, the resulting equation is separable and can be solved via standard ODE techniques to get a relationship between $t$ and $r$. I'm pretty sure this question has been asked & answered on this stack but I can't find it just now.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

How to solve a particular differential equation is a mathematical question more suited to Math SE.

You’re considering only purely radial motion.

I only wanted radial motion, not orbits - just regular "falling" to the ground. Thanks for your answers.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19388/2451 and links therein.
