# Acceleration dependent on displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

A particle starts its motion from origin with a velocity $4$ m/s in positive $x$ direction. It's acceleration is related with position as $a = (2x + 2)$. Find magnitude of velocity of particle at  $x=4$.

I've tried a lot to bring it with respect to time. But I could not proceed any further. Is this problem valid or there's a typo in my book.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the position at time $t$, if acceleration depends on position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320752/how-do-i-get-the-position-at-time-t-if-acceleration-depends-on-position)

Answer (score -1):

$$a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt}.\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dt} = v.\frac{dv}{dx}$$

Comment: Please don't post complete solutions to homework questions.  Please delete this answer.

Comment: It's a very common trick that every new student should know of and there's no other way I could have put it across. And it's not a complete answer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You should solve a differential equation:
$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2x+2$
Solve for x and than calculate the derivative of x that is the velocity.