Calculating time for acceleration varying with distance
Question is basically the title
Like if something is falling towards a body with mass M (mass is not that big so Newtonian equations will be fine) from a distance x from it's center. How long will it take to travel to another point x2?

In general you need to solve the differential equation that Newton's second law gives you. The solutions will be very different depending on how the force depends on position and/or velocity.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19813/2451 and links therein.
