# Free fall from space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

If you leave a ball weighing 10 kg at a height of 500 km above sea level (neglecting air friction). 
How can calculate how long the ball hits the ground and what will be its speed?
[image]

I know that:
On earth I can calculate the time taken to the object to fall by this equivalent:

```
x = x0 + v0t + (at^2)/2
x = 0
x0 = 500000
v0 = 0
a = -g = 10 m/s^2
0 = 500000 - 5t^2
t = 316.227sec
```

Also I know how to calculate the force between objects:

```
g = GMm/r^2
```

Comment: Well, $F=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ and $F=ma$ so that is a starting point. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @jerk_dadt This is not what I'm learning in school so a detailed explanation would really help, still have not tried anything.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field)

Comment: @JohnRennie I did not understand a single word.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us some idea what you already know about calculating equations of motion. I'm afraid that if the answer is "not much" you have a long haul ahead of you. The Wikipedia article gives an equation for the time as a function of distance fallen. Take that equation, put $y_0$ as the initial height (NB distance from the **centre** of the Earth) and $y$ as the final height (again from the centre so the final height is the radius of the Earth) and the equation will give you the time taken.

Comment: There is a [related question here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104541/free-fall-time-with-non-uniform-acceleration-and-some-initial-velocity) and the derivation of the equation is given in an answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/dont-heavier-objects-actually-fall-faster-because-they-exert-their-own-gravity). However you may find this heavy going.

Comment: The working you've shown is correct, but it assumes the gravitational acceleration is constant. However 500km is far enough for the gravitational acceleration to change quite a bit so the fall time is longer than your calculation. The complicated equation in the Wiki article takes this into account. BTW using the full equaiton I get 340 seconds for the fall time.

Comment: @JohnRennie I hate coping from other people. I want to know how to solve this.

Comment: Hi Zilberman Rafael. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael: the derivation is given in [an answer to this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/dont-heavier-objects-actually-fall-faster-because-they-exert-their-own-gravity). It's hard going though.

Comment: @JohnRennie There is no way you can at least explain to me what's going on there?

Comment: I suspect that the level of the course that the OP is taking is non-calculus.  Another hint of that is $g=10$.  It's possible that in the original question it is assumed that gravity is constant.  Perhaps @ZilbermanRafael can tell us if the course has dealt with non-constant forces, and if it is a calculus-based course.

Comment: The trouble is the explanation needs to describe how you set up a differential equation to describe the motion of the particle, and how you solve the equation. This isn't as hard as it sounds - in the UK you do it in the last two years at school (age 17-18) and in more detail in the first year of a univversity physics degree. However to understand it requires a fair bit of maths background. To try and explain it here would be a long answer, and probably an unsuccessful one.

Comment: ZilbermanRafael What is happening here is that the acceleration $a$ is changing with $r$ when you go to a large height of 500km. Near the surface, this acceleration is equal to $g=-10m/s^2$ and it is approximately constant for small heights. To solve your problem what you have to do is use $GM/r^2$ as you acceleration, and then proceed with solving the differential equation in $r$ and $t$. As @garyp suggests, this requires a certain level of knowledge in calculus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time taken for object in space to fall to earth](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34366/)

Comment: @udiboy I'm at 8 grade so I don't know how to solve differential equation (I should learn it in the next month).

Comment: 8th grade is around age 14 isn't it? I couldn't have solved the differential equation describing this motion until around age 18. Good luck, but I suspect your ambition is running away with you.

Comment: Also, his analysis is spot on given the simplifying approximation of constant acceleration (even though the approximation is really not a good one).  @JohnRennie in the US only the top 5% or so of 18 year olds would be able to solve this.