# How can I solve this differential eqution with IVP?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

$$m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-G\frac{Mm}{r^2},  \qquad r(0)=R ,\qquad \dot{r}=v_0>0$$

describes the free fall of an object of mass $m$. $r(t)$ is the distance of m to the center of the earth which is $R$ at $t=0$. $G$ is the gravitational constant.

I don't even know how to start with it. I thought about integrating it twice, but it was apparently wrong. 
And once I get $r(t)$ I am supposed to find the velocity a rocket should have to escape the gravitational area of the earth, and  to do that I'm supposed to assume that the velocity of the rocket at $r(t)=\infty$ is zero.

Comment: For $v_0=0$, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field). Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve it. You can multiply both terms by $\dot r$.
$$
m\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}\frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{GMm}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt} = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2\right] - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{GMm}{r} = 0
$$

Basically $\dot r$ is the integrating factor. We now recognize the potential and kinetic energies over there. Also, we see, $E = T + V$ is a dynamical invariant. Which means:
$$
E = \frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2 - \frac{GMm}{r}, \quad\quad
\frac{dE}{dt} = 0, \quad\quad E = cte.
$$

Now all you have to do is to isolate $\dot r$, separate $r$-terms and $t$ terms, and integrate to explicitly find $\Delta t$, then compute the inverse to find $r(t)$ for a given energy $E$.

Tip: you don't need to solve that differential equation completely and plug initial conditions to realize the escape velocity of a rocket. You can work with conservation of energy directly to find the escape velocity of your rocket (that way you will save a lot of paper).

Comment: The thing is that I have to find $r(t)$ but I don't know how you got from your first to the second equation.