# Closed-Form Equation for a Free Fall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

My eighth-grade physics teacher taught us that the equation for height ($h$) during a free fall in a vacuum is equal to the initial height ($H_0$) minus a constant ($G$, though not the $9.8$ meters per second we know and love) multiplied by time ($t$) squared, divided by $2$.
However, $dh\over dt$ is velocity ($v$), and $dv\over dt$ is acceleration ($a$).  If acceleration were constant, then his formula would be fine.  But acceleration is not constant.  It's $G\over h^2$.  So if acceleration changes, then the velocity is not a perfect quadratic equation, meaning the equation he taught us is wrong.  Presumably he was dumbing it down for $13$-year-olds.

What is the actual equation?  How could you arrive at it?  I tried setting up a second-order differential equation, but got stuck on $$dh = G\int {1\over h^2}dt dt$$
In order to solve this problem I would need to express $h$ in terms of $t$, which is the very problem I am trying to solve.  How does one get around this?  I am in Calc BC, so I would love for a step-by-step solution.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184377/

Comment: You might want to reconsider the meaning of your product $dt\,dt$ in the integral.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think you closed this as the wrong dupe.  This seems to be about how the force/accceleration varies with height due to gravity's change due to height; not so much about the gravity exerted between objects.

Comment: Yeah, do you have a better dupe?

Comment: Nice try.  Can you fill in the gaps that leads to your integral?  Something is wrong there, but I can't tell what without the steps.

Comment: @Qmechanic The integrating the radial freefall seems to be exactly what OP was looking for, only using the term radius instead of height.

Comment: @William, you are confusing $G$ and $g$. And the acceleration is neither $G/h^2$ nor $g/h^2$.

Comment: @William Yes, your teacher is “dumbing it down” but the constant-acceleration approximation is an excellent one for falling apples, projectiles, etc. An important part of doing physics is using good approximations.