# How much time would it take for a positively charged particle to get to an infinite, negatively charged wall?

Tags: coulombs-law

There is a negatively charged wall($q$), which has equal charge density. There is a positively charged particle($Q$) with a mass of $m$, the distance between them is $d$.

How much time would it take for the particle to get to this wall?

EDIT: I messed up on viewing the wall as a stationary charged particle, so I would rather ask the question regarding such one.

---

I have started solving this exercise by the following equation, which is true for the system in its initial position: $F=k*\frac{q*Q}{r^2}$

We also know that $F=ma$, thus $a=\frac{k}{m}*\frac{q*Q}{r^2}$

The problem is, that now we have the value of $a$ against $r$, but we are interested in the time $t$.

So what I did was drawing the plot for $a$ against $r$.

I am not sure at all in the following step of mine: I concluded that the area under the graph equals $\frac1t$, as the area under the curve equals the integral of the acceleration, which is the speed $v$ divided by the distance $r$.

$\frac{v}{r}=\frac1t$

As it is the area under the curve, I looked at the integral of $a$ in the respect of $r$, but the definite integral from $0$ to $d$ has given me strange results (infinity), thus I for some strange reason concluded that the indefinite integral might be useful as well *(I have not learnt calculus, only watched some videos about it, so please bear with me)* . This resulted in in the following: 
$$\int a dr=-\frac{k*q*Q}{m*r}$$

From the previous paragraph I "know" that it might be equal to $\frac1t$, thus I have answered the question as $t=-\frac{m*d}{k*q*Q}$. I am kind of sure that this is not a correct way of doing things, so please correct me, but even though this result at least seems reasonable, as if I were to increase the mass of the particle the time would increase as well, the same is true for the distance, and if I were to increase the charges on any of the two charged objects, the time would decrease.

Comment: Note that $a=\ddot{r}=d^2r/dt^2$ and $r$ is a function of $t$, so it's a bit more complicated that you seem to be directing yourself. You may want to see [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3547/25301) for details of finding the 'time until' for a given force.

Comment: You say an "infinite" wall, but you are using the equations for charge at a point.  Which do you want?  For an infinite wall, the field would be constant and the solution is not difficult.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the word infinite.

Comment: But I just realised that my equation is still not correct as the wall even if not infinite, should not be viewed as a charged particle.

Comment: For a finite wall, the electrical field decays with $1/r$`, so if the particle is infinitely far at start and at rest....