# Does mass affect gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, free-fall

I read somewhere that mass affects gravity– if the mass of the objects are larger, then the force of gravity between them is larger. So, does this mean that the gravity between 2 massive objects is greater than the gravity between 2 smaller objects?

With this, if you drop a golf ball and a rubber ball (same size) on the earth, shouldn't the force of gravity between the rubber ball and earth be greater than the force of gravity between the golf ball + earth? Therefore, shouldn't the rubber ball fall to the ground faster than the golf ball? But this was disproved, so I have some confusion about it.

Comment: Your are confusing force with acceleration.  Check the definitions of both.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Don't heavier objects actually fall faster because they exert their own gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3534/) I also took the liberty to make your post more focussed by removing the second question. It might get reopened now.

Comment: *a golf ball and a rubber ball* Golf balls are mostly rubber, so these aren’t very different and it isn’t obvious which has more mass.